# Custom rewrite not working

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite URLs on my wordpress site to match Googles "seo friendly" policy. I want to rewrite URL's for 3 types of queries generated from search plugin:

**a**) **Location**

> example.com/used-cars/?style1_nonce=5bcd0fed69&location=**london**&autobrand=&automodel=&modelyear=&fueltype=&priceRange=540%2C43000&autotype=&searchauto=

to be:

> example.com/used-cars/**london**/

where **london** can be any location based on user search criteria.

**b**) **Location** + **brand**:

> example.com/used-cars/?style1_nonce=5bcd0fed69&location=**london**&autobrand=**audi**&automodel=&modelyear=&fueltype=&priceRange=540%2C43000&autotype=&searchauto=

to be:

> example.com/used-cars/**london**/**audi**/

where **london** and **audi** can be any location/brand based on user search criteria.

**c**) **Location** + **brand** + **model**:

> example.com/used-cars/?style1_nonce=5bcd0fed69&location=**london**&autobrand=**audi**&automodel=**AUDI+A1**&modelyear=&fueltype=&priceRange=540%2C43000&autotype=&searchauto=

to be:

> example.com/used-cars/**london**/**audi**/**audi+a1**/

where **london**, **audi** and **audi a1** series can be any location/brand/model based on user criteria.

Search results URLs displays **nonce** which is different for each user. I want to skip it from "friendly URL's" so I can index these URL's in Google.

**1**. I have tried, without success:

**Rule Pattern**:

`^used-cars/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?`

**Match**:

```
index.php?style1_nonce=$matches[1]&location=$matches[2]autobrand=$matches[3]&automodel=$matches[4]&modelyear=&fueltype=&priceRange=540%2C43000&autotype=&searchauto=
```

**2**. Following https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule I have tried to test Custom Rewrites and I added the following code to my functions.php file:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^testrewrite/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

I have flushed and regenerated the rewrite rules database but test rewrite seams not working as accessing http://example.com/testrewrite/38 returns 404.

**3**. Mod_Rewrite is enabled.

> ```
> sudo a2enmod rewrite 
> Module rewrite already enabled
> ```

Any advice? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this one

```
function add_rewrite_rules() {
    $newrules = array('^testrewrite/([0-9]+)/?'=> 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]');

    return $newrules ;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Let me know it is working or not.

Comment: Adding your code to functions.php solved problem number 2, I can now access http://example.com/testrewrite/38/ Unfortunately this makes my other posts/pages returns 404 :-( E.g. https://example.com/auto/used-2012-white-hyundai-santa-fe-estate-2-2-premium-crdi-5dr-automatic-194-bhp-full-service-history-for-sale-in-london/ returns 404.

Comment: You can add it multiple there by separating ' , ' as this is an array add your condition adter , like   $newrules = array('^testrewrite/([0-9]+)/?'=> 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]','^used-cars/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?'=> 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]');